# trouble with memory allocation for a class member vector, given an array of objects of that class?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, memory-address

My basic program structure is this:

```
class B1 
{
    vector <someStruct> aStruct; //some struct contains a vector of 'someotherStruct's, etc
    B1() { cout << &aStruct << " ";};
};


class B2 {B1* pB1;};

class A
{
    B1 object_B1;
    B2 object_B2;

    A() { objectB2.pB1 = &object_B1;}; 
};

int main()
{
    vector <A> someA;
    for(int q=0; q < N; q++)
        someA.push_back(A()); 

    cout << endl;

    for (int q=0; q < N; q++)
        cout << someA[q].B2.pB1 << " ";
}
```

So if N was 5, the output would be:
0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828 \n
0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828 0xbffff828

In other words, each object's vector occupies the same space in memory. And program output bears this out as well, since accessing data in the vector through different objects gives the same values, even when they should be different. The other weird thing, of course, is it gives me the same address for the vector as for the object.

Comment: So many syntax error. Why don't people try compiling their sample code before posting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a copy ctor for A and the default copy semantics copy the pointer value from one B2 object to another.  Each item in the struct sees the same address because they are all copied from the same source object.  When this pointed-to object is later destroyed, you'll have UB accessing it.

```
A a1;
A a2 = a1;
assert(a2.object_B2.pB1 == &a1.object_B1);  // Danger Will Robinson!
```

The fix:

```
struct A {
  B1 object_B1;
  B2 object_B2;

  A() { objectB2.pB1 = &object_B1; }
  A(A const &x)
  : object_B1 (x.object_B1)
  {
    object_B2.pB1 = &object_B1;
  }
};
```

You also need a copy-assignment operator because the default one has a similar problem.  Declare this op= as private without defining it if you want it disabled.

Comment: I don't understand what the argument to the copy constructor is supposed to be. And why do I have to change object_B1 to x? can't I just change the value in object_B2.pB1?

Comment: @MattMunson: The argument to the copy ctor is the source of the copy; in "A a2 = a1;", x is a reference to a1.

Comment: If I leave out the line, ': object_B1 (x.object_B1)' does that mean that object_B1 will still have the same address as it did in the object it's copied from?

Comment: @MattMunson: That is a "constructor initializer"; look that up.  It has nothing to do with the addresses of either this->object_B1 or x.object_B1; what it does is copy the one object's *value* to the other, which in this case copies B1's vector data member.

Comment: I realize that, but since this a copy constructor, doesn't that imply that the value was going to be copied anyways?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I get it. In this case your not copying it by assignment but rather are just using the constructor to manually copy it. But how can I make sure the copy constructor gets called, when the creation of the copy is hidden inside of the vector library?

Comment: @MattMunson: Vector uses the copy ctor to copy.

Comment: @Fred Ok. But how does it know to do that? does it look for a ctor that only takes one object of its own type as a parameter?

Comment: @MattMunson: More or less, yes.  A class almost always has a copy ctor in C++ (the compiler generates one if you don't declare one) and "copy ctor" means a very specific set of signatures.  Looking up the "Rule of Three" will probably help.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks a bunch. I think I have it know.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the large number of errors in the program...

```
A.push_back(A());
```

This creates a temporary object of type `A`.  The `object_B2.pB1` member variable is initialized to point to the `object_B1` member variable of this temporary object.

This temporary `A` object is then *copied* into the `someA` container.  The address of this copy's `object_B1` member variable is different, but you don't update the `object_B2.pB1` member variable to point into the new instance.  To do this, you would need to implement a copy constructor (and, for correctness, you would also need to implement a copy assignment operator).

The reason that all of the pointers end up being the same is that the temporary objects are all created in the same location in memory, which makes since, since you are presumably calling `push_back` in a loop, so the temporary object can be created on the stack in the same place at each iteration through the loop.

Comment: @Nawaz:  Yes, it should, and it will, and that is exactly the behavior that the OP is asking about.

Comment: The default copy-constructor should copy the address as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: And that is *exactly* the problem, see the explicit test case in my answer.

Comment: @Fred and @James : I think I misread the question, probably because it's not clear enough.